# How to reconnect to default docker engine

Tags: docker, docker-machine, hyper-v

I have installed docker on my Windows 10, then I've created some images.

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
hello-world         latest              2cb0d9787c4d        3 weeks ago         1.85kB
```

Then I created my first machine using `docker-machine create` connected to `hyperv` driver.
so when I do `docker images` I get:

```
$ docker images 
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
```

My question is  how can I  reconnect to the default docker engine so if I run `docker images` I get:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
hello-world         latest              2cb0d9787c4d        3 weeks ago         1.85kB
```

Answer (score 0):

try `image` instead of `images`

```
docker image list
```

There seems to be some inconsistency w.r.t the two i.e. image/images. Though one would expect the output to be same but there are few differences.